# Save vim tabs without saving vim environment / Reload vim environment

Tags: vim, tabs, environment-variables, session

My vim environment occasionally becomes corrupted because of plugin/user errors (e.g. `:bdelete` in the NERDCommander window), and I'd like to "reload vim".

`:mksession` allows vim to "save" tabs for reopening, but it also saves the broken environment.

I'm thinking any of these could solve the problem:

1. `:mksession` in a way that discards the current vim environment
2. Somehow load an environment from a fresh vim startup
3. Automate my manual solution: Export currently open tabs, restart vim, and reopen each tab

Answer (score 0):

You can influence what `:mksession` persists via the `'sessionoptions'` setting. For instance, by removing `options` from it, changed options and mappings aren't persisted any more.

Also, the saved session is just a Vim script. You can manually / automatically filter out stuff that is broken or not needed. The [session.vim - Extended session management for Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3150) plugin does this sort of postprocessing, too.